# What should be the shape of array while using the fit method in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-regression, data-science

I am new to data science. I am using Spyder (Python 3.7). 
My dataset contains two columns. One for the years of experience of employees (independent variable) and the other one their respective salaries (dependent variable). I split the dataset into training set and the test set. After that while fitting the simple linear regression model, into my dataset using the `LinearRegression`class of the `sklearn.linear_model` library, and using `regression.fit(x_train, y_train)`, I got and error which said`Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`. After this, it printed the x_train array in the IPython Console. And it further said`Reshape your data using  array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample`
I don't understand what to do. I also used the `np.reshape()` to reshape both of my arrays to shape of (10, 2) to make them 2D arrays but still the same error shows up.

Comment: Please provide your code including the input and output. I think your `x_shape` and `y_shape` should both be `(n, 1)` rather than `(n, 2)` or `(n, )` because there is only one dependent variable and independent variable. Try reshape your data like `x.reshape(n, -1)`.

Comment: @zongfan Thank You so much for your answer. I wrote `x_train.reshape(n, -1)` and similarly for y_train and then put them into the `regression.fit()` but again the same error occurred. So, next I directly put the reshape into the fit() as `regression.fit(x_train.reshape(n, -1), y_train(n, -1))` and this time it did not show the error.